# Updating existing KML through a hyperlink in description

Tags: kml, google-earth

I am using Google Earth 5.0 Client. I would like to update a KML file (loaded by a `NetworkLink`) by clicking on a hyperlink in the description/balloonStyle tag of one of its placemarks.

Here is an example:

## A.kml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml>
  <NetworkLink>
    <Link>
      <href>http://www.example.com/B.kml</href>
    </Link>
  </NetworkLink>
</kml>
```

## B.kml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml>
  <Document>
    <Folder id="entities">
      <Folder id="en1_folder">
        <Placemark id = "en1_point">
          <description> 
            <a href="http://www.example.com/getConnections.php?en=id1"
               type="application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml"> Get connections </a> 
          </description>
          <Point>
            <coordinates>...</coordinates>
          </Point>
        </Placemark>
      </Folder>

      There are about 500 such folders, each with its corresponding en# point
      containing a description hyperlink.

    </Folder>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

If a user clicks on a hyperlink, I want to generate a set of LineStrings connecting that point to one or more other points.

For example, `getConnections.php?en=id1` could generate a response like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml>
  <Update targetHref="http://www.example.com/B.kml">
    <Change>
      <Folder targetId="en1_folder">
        <Placemark id="en1_connections">
          <LineString>
            <Coordinates> 
              (en1_coords), (en5_coords), (en7_coords)
            </Coordinates>
          </LineString>
        </Placemark>
      </Folder>
    </Change>
  </Update>
</kml>
```

This doesn't work in GE 5.0. I understand that Update is a child of `NetworkLinkControl` which in turn must be requested by a `NetworkLink` from the same domain as the KML that contains it.
I know there are several workarounds using one or more NetworkLinks, however I am curious to know if there still exists a way to directly update the same KML file by clicking on the description hyperlink.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks,
Max